# Java - Azure Functions How can I pass VM arguments?

Tags: java, azure, intellij-idea, azure-functions, spring-cloud-function

Hi I need to pass the VM argument `-Dspring.profiles.active` to an Azure Function App written in Java.

How can I do that via IntelliJ ?

The change needs to be only for this project. **I don't want to make it global.**

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Add in JAVA_OPTS in `local.settings.json`

```
{
  "IsEncrypted": false,
  "Values": {
    "AzureWebJobsStorage": "",
    "FUNCTIONS_WORKER_RUNTIME": "java",
    "JAVA_OPTS": "-Dspring.profiles.active=local"
  }
}
```